# Split file based on delimiter and then join into separate lines

Tags: bash, awk, sed

I have a file, example.txt

```
0
   A
   B
   C, C, C
   D, D
   E
   F
1
   A, A, A
   B
   C
2
   A
   B
   C
   D, D, D
   E
```

I need to separate the file based on any number and then take the contents between those numbers and join them into a single line, repeating the process for every section of the file:

```
A, B, C, C, C, D, D, E, F
A, A, A, B, C
A, B, C, D, D, D, E
```

---

The best I've come up with is:

```
cat example.txt | sed -e '1,/^[0-9]/d' -e '/^[0-9]/,$d' | paste -sd "," -

A, A, A,   B,   C
```

which is only the middle section, in this case. That, or printing all sections onto one line.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
$ awk 'function prn(line) {if(line){gsub(/[[:space:]]+/, " ", line); print line}}  /^[0-9]/{prn(line); line=""; next} {if(line)line=line"," $0; else line=$0} END{prn(line)}' example.txt
 A, B, C, C, C, D, D, E, F
 A, A, A, B, C
 A, B, C, D, D, D, E
```

Or, for those who prefer code spread over multiple lines:

```
awk 'function prn(line)
      {
          if(line){
              gsub(/[[:space:]]+/, " ", line)
              print line
           }
       }

       /^[0-9]/{
           prn(line)
           line=""
           next
       }

       {
           if(line)
               line=line"," $0
           else
               line=$0
       }

       END{
           prn(line)
       }' example.txt
```

#### How it works

- `function prn(line) {if(line){gsub(/[[:space:]]+/, " ", line); print line}}`

  This defines a function `prn` which compresses excess spaces and prints the line.
- `/^[0-9]/{prn(line); line=""; next}`

  If the current line starts with a number, call `prn` on the contents of `line`, reset line back to an empty string, and skip the rest of the commands and instead jump to the `next` line.
- `{if(line)line=line"," $0; else line=$0}`

  Add the current line to the end of the variable `line`.
- `END{prn(line)}`

  After we have reached the end of the file, call `prn` on `line`.

Comment: Thanks, and that generalizes well to my actual problem. I still really need to learn awk.

Comment: @snd Very good.  By the way, this tutorial is dated but I think it is still a good introduction: [Grymoire Tutorial: Awk](http://www.grymoire.com/Unix/Awk.html)

Answer (score 5):

A shorter idiomatic awk alternative:

```
$ awk '$1=$1{printf "%s%s",$0,(RT==","?OFS:ORS)}' RS="[0-9]|," OFS=", " file1
A, B, C, C, C, D, D, E, F
A, A, A, B, C
A, B, C, D, D, D, E
```

`RS` is the Record Separator . Default is new line, here is set to number or comma
`OFS` is the Output Field Separator = a comma with a single space
`RT` is the record separator value in use
`ORS` is the Output Record Separator , new line by default
`$1=$1` is an idiomatic assignment that forces awk to recalculate fields and records based on  the values of OFS,ORS,etc
`(RT==","?OFS:ORS)` Is a ternary if operation based on the synthax
`(condition?action for true:action for false)`.

Answer (score 2):

Following `awk` may also help in same.

```
awk '/^[0-9]+/ && val{print val;val="";next} FNR>1{sub(/^ +/,"");val=val?val ", " $0:$0} END{print val}'  Input_file
```

***Explanation:*** Adding explanation too here for above command with it's non-one liner form too now.

```
awk '
/^[0-9]+/ && val{        ##Checking condition here if a line starts from digit(s) and variable named val is NOT NULL if it is TRUE then do following:
  print val;             ##printing the value of variable val here.
  val="";                ##Nullifying the variable val here.
  next                   ##next will skip all further coming statements.
}
FNR>1{                   ##Checking condition here if line number is greater than 1 then do following:
  sub(/^ +/,"");         ##Using sub utility of awk to substitute all starting space with NULL of the current line.
  val=val?val ", " $0:$0 ##creating variable named val and concatenating its own value with it each time it comes here.
}
END{                     ##This is awk programs end section here. Which starts once whole Input_file is being read.
  print val              ##Printing the variable named val value here.
}
'  Input_file            ##Mentioning the Input_file name here.
```

Answer (score 2):

**sed**:

```
 echo `sed 's:$:,:' example.txt` | sed -r 's:^:, :;s:,\s*[0-9]+,\s*:\n:g;s:^\s*::;s:,? *$::'
```

**perl**:

```
 perl -p0777e 's:^:, :;s:\n\s*:, :g;s:,\s*[0-9]+,\s*:\n:g;s:^\s*::;s:,?\s*$:\n:' example.txt
```

---

1. `echo...`, or `perl -p0777...` - treat whole file as a single long line (containing newline characters (`perl`) or spaces (`echo`))
2. `s:^:, :` - add an extra comma in the beginning
3. `s:\n:,:g` - replace all newlines with commas
4. `s:,\*s[0-9]+,\s*:\n:g` - replace all numbers surrounded by commans with newlines

Answer (score 1):

Another sed

```
sed -n '
N
:A
$bB
/\n[ ]*[0-9][0-9]*$/!{
N
bA
}
h
s/\n[^\n]*$//
:B
s/[^\n]*\n[ ]*//
s/\n[ ]*/, /g
p
$b
x
s/.*\n//
bA
' infile
```